# Can't locate resource:/edu/cmu/sphinx/models/en-us/en-us/ in netbeans

Tags: java, netbeans, speech-recognition, cmusphinx

`Configuration configuration = new Configuration();

```
   configuration.setDictionaryPath("resource:/edu/cmu/sphinx/models/en-us/cmudict-en-us.dict");
  configuration.setLanguageModelPath("resource:/edu/cmu/sphinx/models/en-us/en-us.lm.bin");
```

System.out.println("setAcousticModelPath"+configuration.getAcousticModelPath());

```
       StreamSpeechRecognizer recognizer = new StreamSpeechRecognizer(configuration);
InputStream stream = new FileInputStream(new File("test.wav"));

    recognizer.startRecognition(stream);
       SpeechResult result;
    while ((result = recognizer.getResult()) != null) {
    System.out.format("Hypothesis: %s\n", result.getHypothesis());
}
recognizer.stopRecognition();
```

`
Here I have put the resource files to project src directory as shown in the image below[The structure of netbeans project](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1RrTf.png)
I have also tried putting that file in root directory but still it doesn't works.

Answer (score 0):

I created the jar file by putting the models into the edu.cmu.sphinix and built it with gradel, now I have surpassed the problem.